# Adding disqus comments to sinatra app using slim template language

Tags: sinatra, disqus, slim-lang

I have an app built with Sinatra. One of the pages is called "discussion" and I chose to power the comments with disqus. I copied the universal instructions

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
  var disqus_shortname = 'voltairequotes';

  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

but i converted the code to [slim](http://slim-lang.com/) and added them to the page

#### discussion.slim

```
h2 Discussion Area

p Add your comments below and please cite what quote you are referring to.

#disqus_thread
javascript:
  /!* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
  | var disqus_shortname = 'voltairequotes';

  /!* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  | (function() {
      | var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
      | dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
      | (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
  | })();
noscript
  | Please enable JavaScript to view the
  a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow"  comments powered by Disqus.
```

But the comments will not show up. But the code shows up when I go to inspect element.

[image]

Not sure what I am missing or perhaps i have a typo or mistake in my markup

Comment: FYI, I wrote an extension to handle this https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-disqus, it may come in handy.

Comment: @iain that will be useful. Do you have a blog post on how it works?

Comment: I like to think of myself as principled and efficient, which to others means lazy, so no, I haven't ;) There is an [example in the readme](https://bitbucket.org/yb66/sinatra-disqus#markdown-header-example) (unfortunately, the documentation scanner on Rubygems doesn't render it properly). However, a blog post is a good idea, I'll add it to my todo list :)

Answer (score 0):

OK i solved the problem overall. Hence I am posting the solution to help others.

But leaving the question since I still fail to see how my first attempt was unsuccessful.

What I did was move the javascript to its own file, which is a good practice anyways.

[image]